# WinRT Data Virtualization implementation in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, data-virtualization

I have [asked this question on the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e71b7036-4fb7-4963-a65d-5bcb9fd8f664) (with no success), maybe StackOverflow will prove its strength one more time...

I was attending [Hamid Mahmood's session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-517T) on collection and list apps and was excited to see control-level support for data virtualization. Unfortunately, no details were given on how to implement *IVirtualizingVector* and *IIncrementalLoadingVector*, and it is not evident how to do so by looking at the interfaces themselves.
Can anybody post a sample?

Additional bonus question for SO - is there an easier way to implement IAsyncOperation (needed by IIncrementalLoadingVector implementation) than coding it "from scratch"?

Comment: Your bonus question doesn't seem to be related to the first one at all. Please try to ask one question at a time.

Comment: @svick Yes, it does. Implementing IIncrementalLoadingVector requires implementing IAsyncOperation.

Comment: There is a sample project that has a class implementing `IVirtualizingVector` in "Basic Media Playback" sample.

Comment: @pavel-minaev The one in "Basic Media Playback" seems to be a dummy implementation - it always returns false from IsPlaceholder()

Answer (score 3):

For your bonus question, have a look at the overloaded `Create` method available in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.AsyncInfoFactory`, specifically the overloads that take `Func<Task<T>>`.

Answer (score 3):

I have posted an article on my blog showing how to implement IVirtualizingVector [here](http://andyonwpf.blogspot.com/2011/12/data-virtualization-in-metro-style-apps.html). It describes an overview of how IVirtualizingVector works, as well as an implementation that you can use released as part of the open-source [Cocoon framework](http://cocoon.codeplex.com/). I hope to also show how to use IIncrementalLoadingVector in the future.

Comment: I have used Andy's classes and they work well, btw Andy I posted a question on your blog :)